# Find every first instance of the first dynamic class of element with jquery

Tags: jquery, class, dynamic, instance, target

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="201610 generic-class"></div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class"></div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class"></div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class"></div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class"></div>
</div>
```

The class that starts with "2016" is a dynamic class that I do not know the full name in advance, although this first bit is always the same. This class may or may not appear multiple times in the loop.

**Question**: With JQuery, how do I target every first instance of the first class of every `.wrap > div`?

Not sure if this is helpful, but I played around the following but never got more than the single first instance of the dynamic class:

```
var theClass= $j('.wrap > div').attr('class');
var split = theClass.split(' ');
var firstClass = split[0];
```

Thank you

Comment: What does *"every first instance of the first class of every `.wrap > div`"* even mean? It would help **a lot** if you told us what you expected the result to be.

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to do. Using these as classes is likely a poor way to add them to the DOM in the first place compared to using data attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *"every first instance of the first class of every `.wrap > div`"* you mean these:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="201610 generic-class"></div><!-- This one -->
  <div class="201612 generic-class"></div><!-- This one -->
  <div class="201612 generic-class"></div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class"></div><!-- This one -->
  <div class="201613 generic-class"></div>
</div>
```

Simplest way is really just to loop. If there's only ever **one** `.wrap`, a single loop is sufficient:

```
var seen = Object.create(null);
$(".wrap > div").each(function() {
    var theClass = this.className.match(/\b2016\d+\b/)[0];
    if (theClass && !seen[theClass]) {
        seen[theClass] = true;
        // ...do something with it here
    }
});
```

The `seen` object lets us keep flags for each class name we've seen before, so we know when we're looking at the first one.

Te regex `/\b2016\d+\b/` will match any class name starting with `2016` and having only digits afterward (the `\b` are "word boundary" assertions). That would match what you have, but also ones of other lengths such as `20161` or `201612`. If you want to match **exactly** six digits (per your examples), use `/\b2016\d{2}\b/` instead.

**Live Example:**

```js
var seen = Object.create(null);
$(".wrap > div").each(function() {
  var theClass = this.className.match(/\b2016\d+\b/)[0];
  if (theClass && !seen[theClass]) {
    seen[theClass] = true;
    // ...do something with it here, I'll turn its text green
    $(this).css("color", "green");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="201610 generic-class">201610</div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class">201612</div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class">201612</div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class">201613</div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class">201613</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If there are **multiple** `.wrap` elements, then you need an outer an inner loop:

```
$(".wrap").each(function() {
    var seen = Object.create(null);
    $(this).children("div").each(function() {
        var theClass = this.className.match(/\b2016\d+\b/)[0];
        if (theClass && !seen[theClass]) {
            seen[theClass] = true;
            // ...do something with it here
        }
    });
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$(".wrap").each(function() {
  var seen = Object.create(null);
  $(this).children("div").each(function() {
    var theClass = this.className.match(/\b2016\d+\b/)[0];
    if (theClass && !seen[theClass]) {
      seen[theClass] = true;
      // ...do something with it here; I'll turn its text green:
      $(this).css("color", "green");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div>First wrap:</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="201610 generic-class">201610</div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class">201612</div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class">201612</div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class">201613</div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class">201613</div>
</div>
<div>Second wrap:</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="201610 generic-class">201610</div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class">201612</div>
  <div class="201612 generic-class">201612</div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class">201613</div>
  <div class="201613 generic-class">201613</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was absolutely fantastic! 

I'm sorry if my question was confusing but I tried to keep it abstract so it would be clearer. Didn't work and I will keep that in mind in the future!

Also didn't meant to take so long to answer!

Anyway, your first example was great, it was what I was looking for and I ended up using it it with `/\b2016\d{5}\b/` for 9 characters, hope that's correct.

It's obvious you are a very experienced user, I truly appreciate the time you took to answer this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tiago: Yup, if you have (say) `201602135`, then `\b2016\d{5}\b` is exactly right. Glad that helped!